# array of integers vs. pointer to integer in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If I have `int x[10]` and `int *y`, how can I tell the difference between the two?

I have two ideas:

> 1. sizeof() is different.
> 2. &x has different type --- `int (*p)[10] = &x` works but not `int **q
>      = &x`.

Any others?

In some template library code, I need to determine whether a pointer is a "real" pointer or degenerated from an array. I can't look at source code as the library user does not exist until I write the library. ... I can work around this by rewriting the code, so now this is only a theoretical exercise.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'tell the difference'? Why wouldn't  'examining the type declaration' be a full solution? Do you need to have some different behaviour for a template partial specialization or similar?

Comment: There will be cases where the sizeof is equal.
Anyway, the easies way to see the difference is to look at the source code. What is the real problem you're trying to solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sizeof` idea is not very good, because if the array happens to have a single element, and the element type happens to be the same size as a pointer, then it will be the same size as the size of a pointer.

The type matching approach looks more promising, and could presumably be used to pick a template specialization (if that's what you're up to).

Answer (score 5):

There is no general method - you either already know the type because you have just declared the object, or the type will have decayed to a pointer and been lost. Please explain what problem you are trying to solve by differentiating between them.

Comment: Ditto                           :-)

Comment: I suspect he's either writing some template code that differentiates between an array or pointer or trying to write an array count function/macro that fails for pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you aren't trying to do this for a type declared at function scope:

```
struct yes { char pad; };
struct no { yes pad[2]; };

template <typename T, size_t N> yes is_array_test(T (&arr)[N]);
no is_array_test(...);

#define IS_ARRAY(x) (sizeof(is_array_test(x))==sizeof(yes))
```

Comment: I would prefer SFINAE (= specialized template) to a macro but nevertheless, this general method is the way to go.

Comment: Well, yes. This however is available as a compile time constant.

Comment: MSN: so is the specialized template. ;-) Only the calling syntax changes slightly, ideally it would look like a Boost type trait: `is_array<x>::value`.

Comment: Well, you can't exactly do is_array<variable>::value. You can do is_array<type>::value in a generic way inside a template function, which I guess is what you are referring to. But I think we both know how to solve this problem both ways, so we both win!

Answer (score 0):

int x[10] will be allways allocated on the stack at the place were it is called. x value can never be changed.

int *y simply declare a pointer to a memory , the pointer value can be changed at any time without any restrictions.

int *y can have any arbitrary value. Meaning , it can point to stack-allocated Memoryor heap allocated memory. Technicly it can also point to invalid memory but that won't make any sense.

int x[10] guarntee you are allways pointing to a valid memory and you don't have to worry about memory deallocation.

when using int* y , you have to worry about the memory it is pointing to .

Also keep in mind that the lot your porgram has dynamically allocated memory the more it will be exposed to errors , leaks , performece issues , allocation\deallocation assimetry  and many other kinds of problem.

Answer (score 0):

They are different types.

How do you tell the difference between an int32 and a uint32, or a uint32 and a char[4]?

The right way to think of it is that the only way that they are similar is that in certain contexts (including array indexing!) an array promotes into a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the equivalent in g++ 4.5 C++0x mode for char arrays and it won't let me both define

```
template <typename T>void moresilly(const T v[],const char *description)
```

AND

```
template <typename T>void moresilly(const T *v,const char *description)
```

it claims both are the same type.

I had a function:

```
template <typename T>void silly(const T & v,const char *description)
{
    cout<<"size of "<<description<<" is "<< sizeof(T)<<endl;
    moresilly(v,description);
}
```

It correctly gets the size of an array if passed and of a pointer if passed, but I can't use moresilly to distinguish between pointer and array, so I can't tell a 4 character array from pointer to n characters.

It might work, sort of, to have templates on T[1],T[2], T[3] etc. but there's already a post saying that different compilers handle that (or some similar case) differently and that gnu prefers a pointer match in C++11.

... added later:
After some experiment I found something that works in g++ 4.5

```
template <typename T,size_t L>void moresilly(const T (&v)[L],const char *description)
{
    cout<<description<<" is an array"<<endl;
}
template <typename T>void moresilly(const T *v,const char *description)
{
    cout<<description<<" is a pointer"<<endl;
}
template <typename T>void moresilly(const T v,const char *description)
{
    cout<<description<<" is a raw value"<<endl;
}
template <typename T>void silly(const T & v,const char *description)
{
    cout<<"size of "<<description<<" is "<< sizeof(T)<<endl;
    moresilly(v,description);
}
```

with the following works properly

```
    silly("12345","immediate string of 5 characters plus zero");
    silly((const char *)"12345","immediate constant char pointer of 5 characters plus zero");
    char testarray[]="abcdef";
    silly(testarray,"char array of 6 characters plus zero");
const char testarray2[]="abcdefg";
silly(testarray2,"const char array of 7 characters plus zero");
```

Note that if the first function is defined with "const T v[L]" instead of "const T (&v)[L]" it doesn't work, never matching anything.

So I solved your problem but don't expect this to work in other versions of the compiler including future ones.  This is why I hate c++.  Somehow the definition of the language is so unclear that compilers are full of unstable edge cases.

This is a useful trick though, I may use it.